# SIGABRT when retrieving value from future

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem using C++11 futures. When I call `wait()` or `get()` on the future returned by `std::async`, the program receives SIGABRT signal thrown from the `mutex` header. What could be the problem? How to fix it?

I use g++ 4.6 on Linux. Pasting the following code to ideone.com causes the same problem.

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int calculate() {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    auto result = std::async(calculate);
    result.wait();// <-- this aborts
    int value = result.get();// <-- or this aborts as well if previous line is commented out.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426141/asynchronous-function-call-c0x

Comment: @Anders K.: That does not seem to be of any use here. I would be satisfied with the default launch policy if it didn't crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be solved by adding `-pthread` switch to `g++`.